Array or tabular in Beamer breaks \if
I want to have an array or tabular environment in an \if statement in Beamer. If I have an article, this compiles just fine:
\documentclass{article}

\def\x{1}
\begin{document}

\if\x1
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
x & y
\end{tabular}
\fi


\end{document}

But, if I switch to Beamer:
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\x{1}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\if\x1
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
x & y
\end{tabular}
\fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}

then I get the error

<inserted text>
\fi  <*> main.tex
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text. This kind of error happens when you say \if...' and forget the matching \fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.
! Emergency stop. <*> main.tex

when compiling this in Overleaf.
How do I fix or avoid this issue?

Try bracing the tabular environment {\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}. Or use the [fragile] option in \begin{frame}[fragile].

@campa It would be nice if you would post an answer!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It was a wild guess, I couldn't test. If you know why this happens, be my guest :-)

Either solution works! I'll accept that as an answer

@campa I didn't trace it in the code, but given that using fragile avoids the problem, I assume it is about how beamer processes the frame content. Anyway, both your solutions would make a nice working answer!

The {frame} environment grabs its entire content in order to work out overlay specifications, and must re-interpret it afterwards when typesetting. This is known to raise some difficulties every once in a while.
Two solutions come to mind, both working in this case:

You can try to "hide" tabular constructs within braces, or
you can use the fragile option

\documentclass{beamer}

\def\x{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This works
\if\x1
{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
x & y
\end{tabular}}
\fi
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
This works too
\if\x1
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
x & y
\end{tabular}
\fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}


You can hide the object in the argument to a command.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{show}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showornot}{>{\TrimSpaces}m}{\iftoggle{show}{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table not shown}
\showornot{
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  x & y
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}

\toggletrue{show}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table shown}
\showornot{
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  x & y
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


